# Changing information about site in search engine (Google)

Tags: search, seo, yandex

I want to change the search result in a search engine as indicated in the following image:
[Advanced search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW96Z.jpg).

Need direct instructions on how to:

1. Change the description of your site in the search engines.
2. Make a search on the site in the search results.
3. Add the subcategory in the search results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To change the description of your site in the search engines change the meta description on each page of your website.

```
<meta name="description" content="Enter your new description here which you want to show in the search engines.">
```

and then request google webmaster to crawl it once again.